# Grabbing a value from a SELECT box in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, html-select

I've got a drop down select box that grabs each relevant value from an SQL database in a loop.

I'm creating a form so that when the "Submit" button is pressed it redirects to a PHP file that carries out the INSERT SQL statement. However because the select options are coming from a loop I'm unsure of how to grab the right value when its selected as it just grabs the last value gained from the loop.
I'm pretty sure that the way I have done it is the wrong way to go

```
<?php
echo"<select name='ModuleTitle' id='ModuleTitle' style='width:100%;'>";
echo"<option>Select...</option>";
        //3. Perform database query
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Module
        ORDER BY  `ModTitle` ASC;", $connection);
        if(!$result){
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
    //4. Use Returned Data
    while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $module = $row5[2];
        echo "<option name='{$module}'>".$row5[2]."</option><br />";        
}

echo"</select>";        
echo "<a href='submitREQ.php?id={$module}'><img src='images/submit.jpg' height='27'></a>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<a href` you should use `<input type="image" value="submit" src="images/submit.jpg" />`

To grab the value after the form is submitted you should use: `$ModuleTitle = $_POST['ModuleTitle'];`  or `$_GET` if the method is `get`.

Comment: If you don't have it already, be sure to enclose the entire thing in a form.  So at the top you'll need `<form action="submitREQ.php" method="post">` and at the bottom put `</form>`

Comment: I have it in a form, should I replace "<a href='submitREQ.php?id={$module}'><img src='images/submit.jpg' height='27'>" with <input type="image" value="submit" src="images/submit.jpg" /> ? What we had before brings back a value, but only the value at the end of the loop and not the selected one

Comment: Yes replace it that way.  If you do that and use `$id = $_POST['ModuleTitle'];` in your php then it will grab the selected value.

Comment: The reason is that the `<select>` name is `ModuleTitle`.

Comment: Just curious where the GET is going to get the id from, if I'm getting rid of submitREQ.php?id={$module}' ?

Comment: It will get the id from the `<select>`.   When you submit the form the `<select>` control will pass the `<option` value to the name `ModuleTitle` (since that is what you named your select control)

Comment: By the way, if you are using `action="get"` then you should use `$id = $_GET['ModuleTitle'];`

Comment: Just changed method="post" to method="GET"